# How do I stop <TouchableOpacity> from taking up the whole row and being pressable from anywhere in that row?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm creating a custom header and I don't want the back button to be pressable from anywhere in the row. Not sure how to fix this, I don't have any flex: 1 applied.

```
export default function IconButton({ iconName, color, size, onPress, style }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[style]} onPress={onPress}>
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

```
    <SafeView style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        // Custom Header
        <IconButton
          iconName={'keyboard-backspace'}
          size={25}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Welcome')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.title}>Create a new account</Text>

        <Form>
          ...
        </Form>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </SafeView>
```

[image]

Pressing anywhere in the row of the arrow will trigger the onPress, how do I stop this?

Comment: Just give `height` and `width` to `TouchableOpacity` where you want press function to work :)

Comment: @Rohit , thank you! I don't know how I missed that haha

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple fix as Rohit commented.

Adding a width or height will stop it from being pressable in its row. Thanks, Rohit!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get you component flexible you can wrap you pressable with a view  and write the above styles:

`const createStyles = () => StyleSheet.create({ container: { alignSelf: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', }`

it's not necessary to give height and width.It takes it from the Svg (child) you have wrapped it with.

It is a good method to put into your styling Background color and watch the changes you are making.